# Why does my Unity Android export fail with "No resource identifier found"?

Tags: unity, android

When I try to export my Unity game to Android, I get this error:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
>
> AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'isGame' in package 'android'
>
> AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'banner' in package 'android'

What could cause this?

Comment: When I get build errors I usually start by googling the exact error message. For example, searching `No resource identifier found for attribute 'isGame'` returns http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/914949/unity-5-androidmanifestxml4-error-no-resource-iden.html

Answer (score 1):

The reported error commonly derives from not having your Android SDK up to date. This has been confirmed at [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/914949/unity-5-androidmanifestxml4-error-no-resource-iden.html) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355684/androidmanifest-app-banner-issue).

Updating your Android SDK to *at least* API level 21 (also known as Lollipop) should fix your problem. Regardless, it is a good idea to ensure you have the *latest* version of the Android SDK.

[Further confirmation at Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/935508/failed-to-re-package-resources-unity-5.html) implies that Unity *should* have detected this problem, and automatically attempted to upgrade your SDK. The fact that it *does not* implies the presence of a bug, which you may [consider reporting](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/bug-reporting)

---

Contrary to the other answer, you ***do not*** need to specifically target the API, in your build. `isGame` and `banner` are both members of the [application declaration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html). The application declaration has an API *requirement* of API Level 1 - it has always been there.

As such, versions that pre-date Lollipop will not freak out over newer inclusions; they just wont use them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build against **API level 21** or higher.
If using Ant, then edit **project.properties** and use:

```
target=android-21
```

Comment: In contrast to *building against* API 21, **You should only need to have the API 21 SDK installed**.

Comment: This answer still *works* (you have to have the SDK installed to build against it); but it implies an unnecessary restriction on users that follow it.